# When printing an object with println in java (calling toString), NULL is being printed and not the output I expected

Tags: java, oop, nullpointerexception, null, abstract-class

I was working on a project that involves using abstract classes and methods. The idea is we have general abstract class **Shape** and three subclasses **Circle**, **Triangle**, and **Rectangle**. I have to calculate the area of each shape, so I defined an abstract method in the Shape class: **calculateArea()** that returns the area of a shape. Each subclass overrides this method and calculates its area respectively. I have a tester class DrawingApp that instantiates an array of 10 random shapes and computes the total area of the shapes. Now I looked over my code and the logic seems to be correct. In the DrawingApp class, I instantiate 10 different objects of type Shape using a for-loop and a random number between 1 and 3 is generated, if the number is 1 then we instantiate a Circle and vice versa (2 would be a Rectangle and 3 for Triangle). Now I think this seems to be correct but after instantiating 10 random objects, I would like to print out the area of each different shape. So I used a for loop to iterate over the 10 objects that were created and call: System.out.println(randomShapes[i]). Now the problem I face is when iterating over the 10 Shapes, it prints **null** 10 times instead of printing the area of each shape. I looked over my code multiple times but cannot figure out why it is doing this. Is it a NullPointerException error? I'm really confused and any help would be very helpful. Thank you. Also  Below I listed the following classes: **DrawingApp.java**, **Shape.java**, and **Circle.java**. I did not list the other classes (Rectangle and Triangle) because it does the same thing as **Circle.java** and the only difference is the formula.

**DrawingApp.java**

```
class DrawingApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shape [] randomShapes = new Shape[10]; // an array of 10 random shapes: Circle, Triangle or Rectangle
        // create 10 random shapes
        for(int i = 0; i < randomShapes.length; i++) {
            double randomNumber = Math.random() * (3 - 1 + 1) + 1; // generates a random between 1 and 3
            // circle
            if(randomNumber == 1) {
                double circleRadius = Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1) + 1; // generates a random between 1 and 10
                randomShapes[i] = new Circle("Circle", circleRadius);
            }
            // rectangle
            else if(randomNumber == 2) {
                double length = Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1) + 1; // generates a random between 1 and 10
                double width = Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1) + 1; // generates a random between 1 and 10
                randomShapes[i] = new Rectangle("Rectangle", length, width);
            }
            // triangle
            else if(randomNumber == 3) {
                double height = Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1) + 1; // generates a random between 1 and 10
                double base = Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1) + 1; // generates a random between 1 and 10
                randomShapes[i] = new Triangle("Triangle", height, base);
            }
        }
        // prints null instead of area of that shape
        for(int i = 0; i < randomShapes.length; i++){
            System.out.println(randomShapes[i]); // call toString and display shape name, id, and area
        }
    }
}
```

**Shape.java**

```
abstract class Shape {
    protected static int id = 0; // id for each shape
    protected String label; // the shape label
    
    public Shape(String label) {
        id++;
        this.label = label;
    }
    public abstract double calculateArea(); // abstract method for calculating the area of a shape

    // getters and setters 
    public static int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
}
```

**Circle.java**

```
class Circle extends Shape {
    private double radius;

    public Circle(String label, double radius) {
        super(label);
        this.radius = radius;
    }
    @Override
    public double calculateArea() {
        double area = Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
        return area;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Id = " + super.getId() + ". Shape = " + super.getLabel() + ". Area = " + this.calculateArea();
    }
}
```

**Output (disclaimer: The circle points do not get printed. It just a list for StackOverflow.**

- null
- null
- null
- null
- null
- null
- null
- null
- null
- null

Comment: My guess: you're comparing a `double randomNumber ` to an integer.  Obviously the double will be something like `3.124519` and not exactly 3.  Make your random number an `int`.

Comment: You sir are correct. Thank you very much for pointing that out. It works now!! :)